# Single page applications Nginx Django Python and port forwarding

Tags: javascript, python, django, nginx, seo

I want to run my single page app in production. 
Since I'm using rest API and ajax calls to deliver the content from the backend to the front end for SEO reasons I need to have a no javascript version of my content available for the crawler bots.
I have a url for no javascript version of the content but since the webserver is running on port 8000 to access the no javascript files I need to navigate to mydomain.com:8000/nojs.

My apps url looks like the code below:

```
urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^nojs/$', views.nojs),
               url(r'^blog/all/$', views.allTitles),
               url(r'^post/(?P<id>[\d+]+)/(?P<title>[\w+]+)/$', views.viewArticle)
]
```

and my nojs method is simply a hello message:

```
def nojs(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

I'm guessing I need to create some changes in my Nginx configuration to access the nojs method without using the 8000 port after my domain name.
How can I navigate to mydomain.com/nojs and get the hello message without using the 8000 port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the files in the nojs folder I needed to add the following to the Nginx config file for the domain and that would forward the traffic from port 8000 to port 80.

```
location /nojs {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/nojs/; #or whatever port you are using
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

}